# Couldn't fetch the dummy js data to my table in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to development side. I am facing the following error report in Vue js 3

```
115:5 error  'vendorTable' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars   
115:23  error  'Vue' is not defined    no-undef   
117:3   error  Object declaration on 'data' property is deprecated. Using function declaration instead  vue/no-deprecated-data-object-declaration.
```

**In template section**

```
  <table id="vendorTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Vendor Code</th>
        <th>Vendor Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="row in rows" :key="row.vendorTable">
        <td>{{ row.vcode }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.vname }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**In script**

```
<script>
var vendorTable = new Vue({
  el: "#vendorTable",
  data: {
    rows: [
      {
        vcode: "VC001",
        vname: "ABC Pvt Ltd",
      },
      {
        vcode: "VC002",
        vname: "XYZ Pvt Ltd",

      },
    ],
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: if your project is created by vue-cli, check https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html for introduction

Comment: Reported errors seem to be related to ESlint check. 
Are you using Vue Single File Component? 
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Comment: Hello, it looks like you are running into linting errors. The linter is a program that verifies if your code is violates certain style and formatting rules. These are usually not really errors (like in software errors/bugs), but should be considered as warnings.

Answer (score 0):

`new Vue` is the syntax for Vue version 2.x, For Vue 3 you need to do this:

```
Vue.createApp({
  el: '#vendorTable',
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with new vue3 sytax

```
 const vendorTable = {
      data() {
        return {
        rows: [
          {
            vcode: "VC001",
            vname: "ABC Pvt Ltd",
          },
          {
            vcode: "VC002",
            vname: "XYZ Pvt Ltd",
    
          },
        ],
        }
      }
    }
    
    Vue.createApp(vendorTable).mount('#vendorTable')
```

and

```
<tr v-for="row in rows" :key="row.vendorTable">
```

"row.vendorTable" wrong use change it with this "row.vcode"